# BATCH need help to replace text and special characters

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a batch code that's working except it returns: Belgi‰ at some point.
So I would like to change that into België when I merge these results:

CODE:

```
@echo off
systeminfo > Test2.txt

echo Please don't close the window, the program is still running...

findstr /C:"Host-naam:" /C:"Naam van besturingssysteem:" /C:"Geregistreerde     eigenaar:" /C:"Product-id:" /C:"Computermodel:" /C:"Computerfabrikant:" /C:"Type systeem:" /C:"Systeeminstellingen:" /C:"Landinstellingen voor invoer:" /C:"Totaal fysiek geheugen:" Test2.txt >> Test1.txt

echo This is the IPv4 adress: >> Test1.txt
ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4" >> Test1.txt
echo: >> Test1.txt

echo This is the IPv6 adress: >> Test1.txt
ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv6" >> Test1.txt

DEL Test2.txt

EXIT
```

So now it returns at some point:

```
Systeeminstellingen:                 nl-be;Nederlands (Belgi‰)
Landinstellingen voor invoer:        nl-be;Nederlands (Belgi‰)
```

I want it to give back:

```
Systeeminstellingen:                 nl-be;Nederlands (België)
Landinstellingen voor invoer:        nl-be;Nederlands (België)
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT1:
I tried adding **chcp 1252** above systeminfo > ... And it worked, thanks for the help.

EDIT2:
I just saw I get his output for IPv6 address, I would like to get rid of the %14 and %11 and for every other address that might get the %... after it.
how can I do that?

```
Link-local IPv6-adres . . . . . . : fe80::1191:e4de:e3e9:277%14
Link-local IPv6-adres . . . . . . : fe80::e400:4433:12c3:2001%11
```

EDIT3:
So it seems like there is some kind of code to remove the % sign at the IPv6 adress. However the following doesn't work.

```
ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv6" | findstr /v /r "%[0-9]" >> Test1.txt
```

Comment: Only a guess, try to change your codepage. Add `chcp 1252` before the line `systemino ...`

Comment: thanks, that worked.

However i edited the post to add another question, just want to check if it's normal.

Comment: You can get rid of the "%" in the IPv6 addresses by including the following at the end of  your findstr command (but before redirecting it to Test1.txt: `| findstr /v /r "%[0-9]"`

Comment: @theglossy1 Sorry, but I don't get it.
Does it have to look like this:

`ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv6" | findstr /v /r "%[0-9]" >> Test.txt`

Comment: Exactly. The "/v" means "match the lines that don't contain the text. The [0-9] is part of the regular expression indicating any number. Findstr's regex engine is pretty weak, but sufficient for basic matching.

Comment: @theglossy1 I get an empty output when i try it.
I will add an EDIT3, maybe you can edit it to see what i do wrong?

Comment: Let us see the output of Test1.txt before adding in my suggestion (findstr /v ...)

Comment: @theglossy1 here's the initial output: http://prntscr.com/60v7ai
Or should i edit the post to add it into the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `chcp 1252` in the beginning of the batch file changes the codepage.
So now the output will be in the correct format (ANSI).

Part2:
`%` is the scope of the address
Read at [Why is there a percent sign '%' in the IPv6 address?](https://superuser.com/a/99753)

Comment: Could you help me please with looking at EDIT2?
I would like to know if that output is normal or if i need to change something else in the code.

Comment: I just checked it and it seems like he adds it afterwards.
Originally the ipv6 adress is withouth the %14.
Any idea how i can solve that problem?

Comment: Oh, so I can't delete it, or it's better to not do it.
And it won't do any harm or cause any problems if I let it stand there?

Answer (score 0):

If you open Test1.txt in a text editor is the wrong output displayed, or only if you view it via "type Test1.txt" or "more Test1.txt" from the command-line? Non-ASCII characters generally do not display well in cmd.exe. You can change the code page with the "chcp" command to 65001 (*chcp 65001*) to support unicode, but it causes other problems (e.g., the *more* command doesn't work properly).

Comment: When i open it in a text editor, like notepad, it displays the wrong output.
However i wonder if it's possible to change that one sign that gives a problem.
I searched alot after it, but it never worked properly.

So is there a code that i can write, so it will scan the document and change the word i want?